# php security quickly

Tags: php, security

in the next few days I'll have to secure a site (which I did)
I thought I would write to the config.php file (called in all the php pages)

```
while($value = current($_POST)){
    $_POST[key($_POST)]=htmlentities($value);
    next($_POST);
}
```

in config.php do you think I'd be siscuro from various xxs and sql injection?
I know that each field must be validated in different ways and that the database would be better not to include html entities.

1) as well as post, get (and maybe request) what other variables should I filter?
2) this method makes me safe from several injections of code (xxs, sql injection etc. ..)?

edit: and if instead of htmlentities I put mysql_real_escape_string would be better?
I want to ensure security is not complete, with data validation, etc. ... but protect from injections as: sql and xxs and other injections

edit: of course if you use "ddd" will also serve a function that I remove the php tags (though I'm sure the site will not run)

thanks :)

Comment: 1) POST, GET, COOKIE, REQUEST 2) No.

Comment: This method helps a little against XSS (and nothing else), but it's not a guarantee, it's a horrible way to code and will break other things for you down the road. Don't do it -- security cannot be added "on top" as an afterthought. If security means anything to the owner of the site, do it properly. Otherwise why bother?

Comment: Just so you know what could happen - I did the same on a site, because it was just hacked, and I copied a function to do it. Turns out the function had a `strtolower()`, and the `base64decode()` would fail, so none of the forms in the clients joomla worked. It was funny as hell :)

Comment: 1. Shorter: `foreach($_POST as &$value) $value = htmlentities($value);` 2. You just removed array functionality in POST 3. Let's say in another file you are checking length of password `if(strlen($_POST['pass']) < 5) // error`. If user user password "f&" he gonna go thru as `&` becomes `&amp;`

Comment: OMG! No wonder sites get hacked! ..

Answer (score 2):

Please never use the words "security" and "quickly" in the same sencence. It probably won't end well... :)

As you already mentioned, it would be "cleaner" not to store the HTML entities in the database, but rather applying `htmlentities` when displaying output (or you make use of a templating engine that handles escaping for you).

`htmlentities` does **not** help against SQL injections (imagine e.g. `htmlentities("' OR 1=1 --")`). You need something like `mysql_real_escape_string` or `$pdo->quote` for that -- although prepared statements would be the best way to go.

However, this is extremly difficult (if not impossible) to apply with an on-top approach. Best have a look at the SQL statements you use and replace them with prepared statements or at least escape any input parameters you use in these queries.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much it. I'd like to add something on top of what you said, the OP could try using http://sqlmap.org/ to test his site for SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

If it was that simple, everybody would be doing it. No one would then advice to use good practices to write secure code. This is not a way to go. Sometimes you might really need those values in your database which can mistakenly be altered by your "catch-all" code. Catch-all is not the way to go for a secure validation mechanism.

> in the next few days I'll have to secure a site

If you continue trying to secure your site this way then it will also remain secure for only **next few days** at the very best.

Answer (score 1):

While it is usually a good idea to do this sort of thing as you build the site. It is logical that different websites require different levels of security. A local website only you access may need none, while a small "intranet" style site might only need basic security.

If you think this site only requires a level of security which can be implemented in a few days. Then I would say the first step would be to go back and make sure that all user input runs through a `mysql_real_escape_string()` function or similar depending on your API (Looks like this function is actually depreciated now).  This function escapes special characters so that it is safe to place it in a MySQL query.

Secondly, in some cases you could use a function like `preg_match()` to check if a string matches an expected input.  This means that you can check Addresses match an Address format and same with Names and Telephone numbers and so on.  This means you can easily limit length and data type.

I would consider this the very first steps in securing a site and will mean that users can't (trivially) save anything they please to your database.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to define data-type for each input, not just globally filter all input data as you proposed. for example:
Consider these fields:
Name:
E-Mail:
Age:
Country:
Address:
Phone Number:
Plain text (textarea):
file (file upload):

Now, if you want to secure these fields, you have to deal with each of them individually.
1- Name: define maximum character length and data type (format), usually Name consists of only (A-z and space) and sometimes one single quota ('), or a dot (.) will be there if someone entered a title like Eng. Mr. 
now, lets check that field, consider

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$name_max_length = 30;
$name_min_length = 5;
$name_pattern = "/[a-zA-Z'\.\ ]{$name_min_length, $name_max_length}/";
if(!preg_match($name_pattern, $name)){
 $error[] = "Please enter valid character for name field";
}else{
 //lets now filter it for safe input
 //above check not passes any kind of XSS, but it passes SQL injection
 //we need to clear it from SQL injection 
 $name = htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES);
 //ENT_QUOTES: Will convert both double and single quotes.
}
?>
```

2- Age: it must be integer, you can simply check it with built-in PHP function:

```
<?php
$age = $_POST['age'];
if(!is_int($age)){
$error[] = "Please enter valid number in Age field";
}
?>
```

3- Plain text: again, use htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES) 
4- File upload:
- Check file extension, you have to create list of white-extensions and then compare uploaded file extension with white list for example:

```
<?php
$extensions = array('png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
if(!in_array($current_file_ext, $extensions)){
 $error[] = "Please select valid file type! (".implode(", ", $extensions);
}
?>
```

Finally, before entering these data, check $error which an array if such error occured

```
<?php 
if(count($error) > 0){
 //means $error contains errors
 //print error values
}else{
 //start inserting your data into database
}
?>
```